# Ошибка сегментирования при поиске в вдухсвязном списке

Tags: c++

код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

struct listelement{
  int value;
  listelement* next;
};

class list{
private:
  listelement* root;
  listelement* end;
public:
  listelement* pointer;

  list(int value){
    this->root = new listelement;
    this->root->value = value;
    this->root->next = NULL;
    this->end = this->root;
    this->pointer = this->root;
  }
  void newElement(int value){
    this->end->next = new listelement;
    this->end = this->end->next;
    this->end->value = value;
    this->end->next = NULL;
  }
  void printAll(){
    this->pointer = this->root;
    while (this->pointer){
      std::cout << this->pointer->value << "\n";
      this->pointer = this->pointer->next;
    }
    this->pointer = this->root;
  }
  void findNext(int value){
    while (this->pointer->value != value && this->pointer->next != NULL) {
      this->pointer = this->pointer->next;
      std::cout << "*";
    }
    if (this->pointer->value == value && this->pointer->next->value == value){
      this->pointer = this->pointer->next;
      this->findNext(value);
      std::cout << "~";
    }
  }
};

int main (){
  list myList(0);
  for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
    myList.newElement(i);
  myList.printAll();
  std::cout << "\nenter searching value\n> ";
  int search;
  std::cin >> search;
  myList.findNext(search);
  int pointer;
  if (myList.pointer!=NULL) pointer = myList.pointer->value;
  std::cout << "searching value: " << pointer << "\n";
return 0;}
```

проблема: при вводе 9 (значение последнего) даёт ошибку сегментирования, при вводе остальных существующих работает как ожидается, при вводе несуществующих значений выводит 9. как так?

Comment: А что это вообще за странная необъяснимая логика в `findNext`? Почему поиск в цикле ведется только до *предпоследнего* элемента, ане до последнего? В чем идея проверки `this->pointer->value == value && this->pointer->next->value == value`? В чем идея рекурсивного вызова?

Comment: @AnT нужно удалить из списка L за каждым вхождением элемента со значением Е один элемент, если он есть и его значение отлично от Е.

Comment: каждый обьект имеет неявный указатель this.  Так что не нужно каждый раз явно использовать его:   this->pointer = this->root;  это то же самое, что  pointer = root;

Answer (score 2):

При поиске 9 ваш цикл заканчивается в состоянии this->pointer->value == 9 и this->pointer->next == NULL, поэтому при последующей проверке попытка доступа к this->pointer->next->value приводит к сегфолту. В случае же поиска несуществующего значения до доступа к this->pointer->next->value дела не доходит, т.к. проверка this->pointer->value == value даёт ложь и следующий операнд оператора && уже просто не проверяется.